# How to Add Additional Search Button?

Tags: customization, filters, search

I have added function to functions.php so authors can search only their published content. I would like to add additional "Search my posts" button to searchform.php so only logged in users would see - have this button for searching posts they published. But I can get it to work. :(

When I click on any button "Search All posts" or "Search My Posts" when logged in it searches only logged in author.

```
function search_author($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('author', get_current_user_id());
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_author');
```

searchform.php

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" method="get" id="searchform">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="searchbox">
            <input class="input" name="s" type="text" id="keywords" value="<?php _e('Search input','mytheme') ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('Search input','mytheme') ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('Search input','mytheme') ?>';}">
                </div>
                <div id="searchbutton1">
                <p class="button search">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="<?php _e('Search All Posts','mytheme') ?> ">
                </p>
                </div>
                <div id="searchbutton2">
                <p class="button search">
            <input type="submit" name="author" value="<?php _e('Search My Posts','mytheme') ?> ">
                </p>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
<?php } else { ?>
<form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" method="get" id="searchform">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="searchbox2">
            <input class="input" name="s" type="text" id="keywords" value="<?php _e('Search input','mytheme') ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('Search input','mytheme') ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('Search input','mytheme') ?>';}">
                </div>
                <p class="button search2">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="<?php _e('Search','mytheme') ?> ">
                </p>
        </fieldset>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to check which button was clicked by user, weather it is search all post or search my post, based on that you can apply filter. Try this..

```
function search_author($query) {
  if($query->is_search) 
  {
    if($query->query_vars['author']=='Search My Posts') 
    {
        $query->set('author', get_current_user_id());
    }
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_author');
```